Handle playback error from just_audio package in Flutter
I want to make an app that can playing audios in Android TV using just_audio Flutter package. I want to use try-catch in Flutter to handle the error when I using audio that cannot play due of com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error. But it didn't work when I try using try-catch in .durationStream.listen, .positionStream.listen, .currentIndexStream.listen and anywhere I try to put try-catch.
After I playing this audio in Android TV, when I click next/previous audio, and even change the song playlist index (using seek(Duration.zero, index : newIndex)), the next/previous audio or changed song playlist index cannot playing and only changing artist and title. Only can playing normally if I start the audio from audio list in files. Strangely, there is no problem when I playing in Android phone and can skip this song without problem.
So, how can I handle this error below?
Error code :
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(19436): Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10280; state: ENABLED
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:614)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(19436):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AudioPlayer(19436): TYPE_SOURCE: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/flutter (19436): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(0, Source error, {index: 8}, null)
E/flutter (19436): 
W/libEGL  (19436): EGLNativeWindowType 0x93df1808 disconnect failed

Package used :
just_audio: ^0.9.39
just_audio_background: ^0.0.1-beta.13
audio_service: ^0.18.14

Updated : Turns out that the problem is when the error audio is only when it placed last index (occurs in Android phone and Android TV). When placed in first and middle index, no problem happens and can skip into another audio index.
